# jQuery - Make Change to Var before storing

Tags: jquery, calendar

I'm a jQuery noob so with that out of the way, I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure out a simple problem.

How to change the value of id=days which is being pulled from a input box on the web page. There is a ui slider which changes the value of the input box.

The the value is calculating the current and future date based on the number of Day listed on the slider/input box.

```
var $days = $("#days");
```

The variable above is lets say is 3 ..... which I want to multiply 3 by 7 .....the value of $days would now be 21 which the jQuery Calender should spit out the correct date.

The end result ... each step of the slider will = 1 week

Thanks...

Edit Added more Info ...... This should be most all of the code using the Calendar.

```
    var date = new Date(baseDate.getTime()); // Calculate the new date
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + $days.val());
    $datepicker.datepicker('setDate', date); // And set into the datepicker
    $datepicker.datepicker({
    buttonImageOnly: true
    });
```

By the way Big Thanks for the Quick Response.....

Note Calender is hidden so theirs no interaction with calender.

Comment: Your code above is setting the variable `$days` to a jQuery object representing a DOM element with the `id` of `days` ... to get the value you need to use `val()` ... but i still dont understand your question ... what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I whipped up a little demo for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help guys and gals.... You gave me some great ideas and with that I solved my problem.

The solution was...

```
date.setDate(date.getDate() + [7 * $days.val()]);
```

Heres the modified code...

```
        var date = new Date(baseDate.getTime()); // Calculate the new date
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + [7 * $days.val()]);
    $datepicker.datepicker('setDate', date); // And set into the datepicker
    $datepicker.datepicker({
            buttonImageOnly: true
    });
```

Theres more than one way to skin a cat. If you have a better or more proper solution please post.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of an input box with `id=days` you would use:

```
var $days = $("#days").val();
```

I made a little demo based on your question, see live here: http://jsfiddle.net/PQkFP/

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
    slide: function(event, ui) {
          var days = $("#slider").slider("value");
          $("#days").val(days);
          // you can see $.datepicker('setDate', <number of days>);
          $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate",(days*7));
        }
  });
});

$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});​
```

Html Snippet:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/
                       1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/
                       1.8/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script>

    </script>
</head>
<div class="demo">

<div id="slider"></div>
    Days : <input type="text" value="" id="days" />
<div id="datepicker"></div>
</div>
​
```

Comment: You're welcome @RichardMax. Consider accepting the answer if it was helpful. See [how accepting works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thanks for the help, still soaking up what you coded to figure out how this can help me with my problem. It is trial and error for me....There is just so much stuff in the estimating script that, I have to be careful not to change to much as it will foul up other parts of the script.....Need to get some sleep will check back tomorrow.... Thanks again for everyone that commented.

Comment: I added some addition code straight out of the file....it will give you a clearer picture of what is going on...Your code looks great and I did try using the ("setDate",(days*7)); in my code but it bombed out will work on it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly understand what you want, but if you want to access the value of an input box you should do this:

```
var days = $('input#days').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab the current value of the input box with the id=days then use the following line of code:

```
var days = $('#days').val();
```

or in your case

```
var $days = $('#days'); // cache object
var days = $days.val();
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to do? Get the date that is ($days*7) days from now?

You can access and change the input fields value like any other js variable,

```
var $days = $("#days").val();
$days = $days*7;
alert($days);
```

That should give you 21!

Comment: I gave it a shot but it bombed out I will work on it for a bit tomorrow.....Thanks.